# Endpoint returns "undefined" when trying to login in the deployed site

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, next.js

I create this site using Nextjs, Nodejs, MongoDB and Express and everything works fine on development, but when I try to login in the deployed site, it returns the following error: https://prnt.sc/0GYgMigoETGc
It adds "undefined" to the endpoint for some reason even through I've added every environment variable to both backend and frontend. Any advise would be greatly appreciated:

This is the handleSubmit funtion in the Login component:

```
 const handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault()    

        try {
            const { data } = await clienteAxios.post('/usuarios/login', { email, password })
            setAlerta({})
            localStorage.setItem('token', data.token)
            setAuth(data)
            router.push('/inicio')

        } catch (error) {
            setAlerta({
                msg: error.response.data.msg,
                error: true,
                visible: true
            })
        }
    }
```

This is the code from the controller:

```
const autenticar = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    // Comprobar si el usuario existe
    const usuario = await Usuario.findOne({ email })
    if (!usuario) {
        const error = new Error('El usuario no existe');
        return res.status(404).json({ msg: error.message, visible: true })
    }

    // Comprobar si el usuario está confirmado
    if (!usuario.confirmado) {
        const error = new Error('Tu cuenta no ha sido confirmada');
        return res.status(403).json({ msg: error.message, visible: true })
    }

    // Comprobar si el password es correcto
    if (await usuario.comprobarPassword(password)) {
        res.json({
            _id: usuario._id,
            nombre: usuario.nombre,
            email: usuario.email,
            token: generarJWT(usuario._id),    
        })
    } else {
        const error = new Error("La contraseña es Incorrecta");
        return res.status(403).json({ msg: error.message, visible: true })
    }
}
```

This is the route:

```
import express from 'express';
import checkAuth from '../middleware/checkAuth.js';
import {
    autenticar
} from '../controllers/usuarioController.js'

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/login", autenticar)

export default router;
```

And the code for the server:

```
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cors from 'cors';
import conectarDB from './config/db.js';
import usuarioRoutes from './routes/usuarioRoutes.js';
/* import configureSocket from './socket.js'; */




dotenv.config();

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;


conectarDB();

// Configurar CORS
const whitelist = [process.env.FRONTEND_URL];

const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.includes(origin)) {
      // Puede consultar la API
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      // No está permitido
      callback(new Error('Error de Cors'));
    }
  }
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// Routing
app.use('/api/usuarios', usuarioRoutes);

// Crear servidor HTTP
const server = http.createServer(app);

// Iniciar servidor
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Corriendo en el puerto ${PORT}`);
});
```

And this is the ClienteAxios file:

```
import axios from 'axios';



const clienteAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${process.env.BACKEND_URL}/api`,
});



export default clienteAxios;
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you defined `clienteAxios`. Looks like there is the issue.

Comment: Thanks Sagar. I've just added the code for clienteAxios in my post.
As you can see, I'm using the env variable for BACKEND_URL so it should work in theory shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in case you guys need to know, I ended up finding a solution after two days of struggle.
The problem was that I wasn't defining tne environment variables correctly.
They were working when added in the next.config.js file, but as I'm not comitting this file in the repository, they wouldn't work in production.
I was adding the env variables in a .env.local file but wasn't aware that for version 9 or higher of Next js env viarables need to be declare as NEXT_PUBLIC_ and then the name of the variable. Here's an example:

`NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL=http://localhost:4000`

For this reason the variable wasn't working on the config axios file.

After renaming the variable, I was able to use it like this:

import axios from 'axios';

```
const clienteAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}/api`,
}); 


export default clienteAxios;
```